# Passing params to POST call with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to add the following query param into my axios call, but for some reason it's not accepting it.

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}

const params = {
  params: {
    isAccepted: true
  }
}

const url = `https://testapi.com`
axios.post(url, params, config)
```

However it works perfectly fine when I do it in this format

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}

const url = `https://testapi.com?isAccepted=true`
axios.post(url, params, config)
```

Am I using the params field wrong in the axios call?

Comment: the request parameters are only added to the URL in a query string for `GET` requests, for `POST` they're included in the request body. A sensible API shouldn't really pay attention to query parameters in the URL for a `POST` request.

Comment: Yes you should add the params this way 
***
const params = {
    isAccepted: true
  }
***

Comment: @RobinZigmond So in my case, the `POST` is paying attention to the query parameters. What should I do in this case?

Comment: What's wrong with your second snippet, which you say works?

Comment: You don't need to set the `Content-type: application/json` header since that is the default

Answer (score 3):

'As can be seen in documentation, axios post request can accept params in config. You are trying to pass parameters on place where your post object should be (data). Parameters can be included in config though.

axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

Here is the documentation.
https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api

Try restructuring the code like this

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  params: {
     isAccepted: true
  }
}

const data = {
   data: 'whatever'
}

axios.post(url, data, config)
```